# cannot purchase Azure VM with the 'CN' account region

Tags: azure

I want to purchase a Linux VM on Azure. However I got following error message when doing this task. My account can purchase and deploy Azure cognitive service, but cannot purchase the Linux VM on Azure. Please help me out.

Offer with PublisherId: 'tunnelbiz', OfferId: 'ubuntulinuxwebserver' cannot be purchased due to validation errors. For more information see details. Correlation Id: '4a525e5f-a6ea-4c2f-aa66-28603da2e9c8' The Publisher: 'tunnelbiz' does not make available Offer: 'ubuntulinuxwebserver', Plan: 'ubuntunginx' in your Subscription/Azure account’s region: 'CN'. Correlation Id: '4a525e5f-a6ea-4c2f-aa66-28603da2e9c8'. Cannot complete purchase as your enrollment for this subscription doesn't allow purchase of marketplace paid products. Your Azure enrollment administrator can enable purchase of paid marketplace products. For more details, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2110642. Correlation Id: '4a525e5f-a6ea-4c2f-aa66-28603da2e9c8'.[{"The Publisher: 'tunnelbiz' does not make available Offer: 'ubuntulinuxwebserver', Plan: 'ubuntunginx' in your Subscription/Azure account’s region: 'CN'. Correlation Id: '4a525e5f-a6ea-4c2f-aa66-28603da2e9c8'.":"StoreApi"},{"Cannot complete purchase as your enrollment for this subscription doesn't allow purchase of marketplace paid products. Your Azure enrollment administrator can enable purchase of paid marketplace products. For more details, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2110642. Correlation Id: '4a525e5f-a6ea-4c2f-aa66-28603da2e9c8'.":"StoreApi"}] (代码: BadRequest)

I tried to change the settings of the Azure account and the settings of the subscription, but I don't know which item should  I change, and how to navigate to it. Please help me out.

Comment: Check this out- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/230819/unable-to-deploy-centos-market-palce

Comment: The error message you're encountering indicates that your Azure enrollment doesn't allow the purchase of marketplace paid products, including the Linux VM you're trying to purchase. To resolve this issue, you'll need to contact your Azure enrollment administrator and request that they enable purchase of paid marketplace products for your subscription.

Comment: Publisher: 'tunnelbiz' does not make available Offer: 'ubuntulinuxwebserver', Plan: 'ubuntunginx' in your Subscription/Azure account’s region: 'CN'.
This error indicates that the Linux VM you're trying to purchase, specifically the "ubuntunginx" plan from the "tunnelbiz" publisher, is not available in your Azure account's region, which is "CN". This means that the publisher doesn't offer this specific VM configuration in your region.

Comment: Cannot complete purchase as your enrollment for this subscription doesn't allow purchase of marketplace paid products.
This error directly addresses the reason why you're unable to purchase the VM. Your current Azure enrollment doesn't allow the purchase of paid marketplace products, including the Linux VM.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that your Azure enrollment doesn't allow the purchase of marketplace paid products, including the Linux VM you're trying to purchase.
"Cannot complete purchase as your enrollment for this *subscription doesn't allow purchase of marketplace paid products*."

Check with your Azure enrollment administrator to enable purchase of paid marketplace products for your subscription.
As per breakdown of the error message:

**Publisher: 'tunnelbiz' does not make available Offer: 'ubuntulinuxwebserver', Plan: 'ubuntunginx' in your Subscription/Azure account’s region: 'CN'.**

This error indicates that the Linux VM you're trying to purchase, specifically the "ubuntunginx" plan from the "tunnelbiz" publisher, is not available in your Azure account's region, which is "CN". This means that the publisher doesn't offer this specific VM configuration in your region.

To resolve this issue, contact your Azure enrollment administrator and request to enable paid marketplace product purchase. Once enabled, retry the purchase. Once your enrollment is updated to allow paid marketplace product purchases, retry the purchase of the Linux VM. The error should be resolved, and you should be able to proceed with the purchase.

Reference Documents:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/230819/unable-to-deploy-centos-market-palce

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/china/resources-faq

Answer (score 0):

i still cannot purchase the ubuntu vm through azure portal, but i can purchase the ubuntu vm through "az vm create" command in powershell with the same azure enrollment. maybe i should choose the right linux publisher or vm image in the azure portal.

Comment: Are you able to get it from the same publisher tunelbiz?

Comment: hi Ariko, no i cannot get it from the publisher tunelbiz.

Comment: here is my ubuntu vm profile. Computer name
linux-vm-lh
Operating system: Linux (ubuntu 22.04)
Image publisher: Canonical
Image offer: 0001-com-ubuntu-server-jammy
Image plan:22_04-lts-gen2
VM generation:V2
VM architecture:x64
Agent status:Ready
Agent version:2.9.1.1

Comment: Can you try using a different Linux image and see just to isolate if it is that image is giving problem?